# Right Shift Division in C

Tags: c

I am an absolute beginner in C and am trying to learn bit shifting. I wrote a tiny program to test division by right shifting.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int shift_divide_by_16(int x);

int main() {

        int x = 32;
        int y = shift_divide_by_16(x);
        printf("%d\n", y);
        return 0;

}

int shift_divide_by_16(int x) {

        x >> 4;
        printf("%d\n", x);
        return x;
}
```

The program prints `32 32`. Why does it not print `2 2`?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `x = x >> 4`. `x >> 4` is a *value*, it doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: `x >> 4;` does a right shift and then throws away the result. Asign it to sometthing

Answer (score 4):

You'd nee to assign the value back to x

```
x = x >> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
x >>= 4;
```